# Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type '"prototype"' jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

**Update:**

Seems the following works:

```
let gaService = TestBed.get(GAService);
```

and spy on gaService.

I am really blank on what I am missing exactly here. The service sends data to google analytics so i have to mock it during my tests. The service itself is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CoreService} from "./core.service";

@Injectable()
export class GAService {
  constructor(
    public coreService: CoreService
  ) { }

  public sendException (
    description: string,
    isFatal: boolean
  ) : Promise<any> {

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      (<any>window).ga('send', 'exception', {
        'exDescription': description,
        'exFatal': isFatal
      });
    });

    return promise;
  }

}
```

and it is mocked like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class MockGAService {
  constructor() {}

  sendException(
    description: string,
    isFatal: boolean
  ): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }

}
```

now during my tests, I have an event that will raise an exception and I want to make sure the sendException is indeed called, so I spied on the event like this:

```
let preventDefaultSpy = spyOn(
  GAService,
  "sendException"
);
```

but it doesn't compile at all with the message:

```
Argument of type '"sendException"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"prototype"'
```

The only way I get it to compile is if i do:

```
let preventDefaultSpy = spyOn(
  GAService.prototype,
  "sendException"
);
```

but then it is never called when I do:

```
expect(preventDefaultSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

just for check, I did a console output on sendException() of the mock and it shows output, hinting it was indeed called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jasmine `spyOn` installs a spy onto an existing object, in your example however you provide a class (first argument).

```
let preventDefaultSpy = spyOn(GAService, "sendException").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
```

Hence your test could be rewritten as follows (no need of `MockGAService`):

```
const service = TestBed.get(GAService);
spyOn(service , "sendException").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));

// do some stuff that is expected to invoke GAService.sendException

expect(service.sendException).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: i figured it out @uminder but since you explained, let me still accept it as an answer, thanks so much.